# User end Respective Time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Hello I am trying to make a web application where users can ask question about their related problems:

The function in which I am stuck is that how can the end users get to know about the timing timing of thew question in their respective time zones?

For example I sitting in Kolkata/Asia time zone posted this question right now and at the same time a person from Western Hemisphere sees the question at the same time saying that this question was posted just 1 min ago.

or suppose a person sees it after 26 hours
so it will show that it was posted 1 day 2 hours ago
or it will show a respective date in respect to its local time zone
for example , posted on 12th Aug, 2014 in Asia/Kolkata
hence it should the proper date in respected usere's local time zone

Just for Note: I am making this web project using php, mysqli, js, ajax

Comment: Save time in database using gmdate(). and when you want to display in front end, convert it into user's timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either standard time like UTC, or server time. It doesn't matter where I am and what time it is now here, nor where you are and what time it is there: it has been several minutes between the time the server accepted your question, and the time it received my answer.